# How to rotate GamesClient's popups

Tags: android, view, popup, libgdx, google-play-games

For some reasons, we had the terrible idea to have an application with a fixed landscape orientation and one "screen" is in portrait. Since we are using libgdx, we only rotate all the drawing part for that screen and we are also able to rotate the Ads:

```
adView.setRotation(-90.0f);
adView.setTranslationX(adView.getWidth() / 2 - adView.getHeight() / 2);
```

We are now integrating the Google Play Game Services but the popups are not displayed in the correct direction (ie. they are displayed in landscape). And I don't know how to rotate them.

```
mGamesClient = new GamesClient.Builder(getContext(), this, this)
                .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
                .setScopes(mScopes)
                .create();
```

I know there is a `setView` method available, but I don't know how to create a view that the GamesClient could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not "ideal" you could probably change the orientation at run time when you go to the portrait screen and then switch back to landscape upon leaving that screen.

For that you'd use [Activity#setRequestedOrientation(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) in your MainActivity (or whatever you called your `AndroidApplication` subclass). You'd likely want to define an interface for invoking this if you are following the normal LibGDX setup.

You should get a resize event in which you can get set up for the new orientation (you'd no longer rotate your rendering or ad).

Alternatively, you could redesign this one screen to be landscape like the rest of the app.

Comment: Changing the orientation was obviously my first idea but we did not managed to do it... I'm a bit surprised because it sounds quite easy but I'll give another look at that approach tonight. Thanks.

Comment: That seems to work, I need to show an achievement to confirm. But at least I can now remove all my ugly hacks.